# Android SharedPreferences and Encrypted SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, encryption, sharedpreferences

I have encrypted my preferences like this

```
    public void setFile(){
        String masterKeyAlias = null;
        try {
            masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            encryptedSharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                    "secret_shared_prefs",
                    masterKeyAlias,
                    this,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                    EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
            );
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and I'm setting and getting values like this

```
prefEditor.putString(SettingsActivity.KEY_NICKNAME,nickName.getText().toString()).apply();
nickname = encryptedSharedPreferences.getString(SettingsActivity.KEY_NICKNAME, "");
```

Everything is okay,but it doesn't set up values in preferences when I'm opening settings, because it uses standart SharedPreferences  xml file.

So, the main question is : How to set up values from Encrypted  SharedPreferences instead of sharedpreferences xml file ?